# print out the occurence of items in list

Tags: python, list

First, a list of identifiers which can be strings or numerical values. Second, a list containing a number of items.
For each identifier (item in the identifiers list) count how often the identifier occurs in the item-list. For each identifier create the following outout:
Identifier  occurred  times within the list.
Replace the markers <> with the actual values for the identifier and the number of occurrences.
Next, remove all occurrences from the item-list and return the pruned list. The pruned list should now only contain items which were not found in the identifiers list.
The Problem is that I dont get any output. How do I have to modify the print command so it gives me the output I need? And also I have Problems with removing the occurrences.

```py
def task_3_2_2(items, identifier): 
    occurences = items.count(identifier) 
    items.pop(occurences)
    print('Identifier {} has occured {} times'.format(identifier, task_3_2_2(items, identifier)))
    print (items)
```

I modified my Code now into this:

```py
def task_3_2_2(items, identifier): 
    i = 0
    for i in items:
        if items.count(i) == identifier:
            items.pop(i)
        print (items)
```

But if I for example call it with

```
task_3_2_2([8, 6, 8, 10, 8, 20, 10, 8, 8],[8])
```

the output is just:

```
[8, 6, 8, 10, 8, 20, 10, 8, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not really loop over the identifiers. So you are only able to process one identifier at a time, although you pass in a list.

Secondly, the if-clause you use

```
if items.count(i) == identifier:
```

does not really do, what you want it to do. You actually check if the *number of occurances* of a item is equal to the identifier. Most probably not what you want.

A possible solution might look like this:

```
def task_3_2_2(items, identifiers): 
    for id in identifiers:
        # Count occurances of identifier id in items
        id_count = items.count(id)
        print(f"Identifier {id} has occured {id_count} times")
        
        # Filter values not equal than identifier id
        items = list(filter(lambda x: x != id, items))
    return items

task_3_2_2([8, 6, 8, 10, 8, 20, 10, 8, 8],[8])
```

**Output:**

> Identifier 8 has occured 5 times
>
> [6, 10, 20, 10]